# Meteor.js 0.6.5 and Cloud 9

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide

For my application I need to run Meteor 0.6.5 (the new release) on Cloud 9.
I tried fixing ports and IP addresses, but I didn't get it working.

I followed this pull request:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1105

And changed these files:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1105/files

But I always get the following error:

> Unexpected mongo exit code 1. starting. 
>   Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting. 
>   Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting. 
>     Can't start mongod

I can't figure out which further changes I have to do. Despite there is no server.js in the new release, that's why I tried to change /webapp/webapp_server.js, but I don't know if this is the right approach.

Hopefully you can give me a hint and the request gets merged soon ;)

Comment: Try to delete mongod.lock, it placed at .meteor/local/db

Comment: I have no file with this name. Folder is empty

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so what I did was connect my Cloud9 IDE to my own Digital Ocean Linux box. Not only did it solve the problem, but now my Meteor development is super fast!

I am thinking it is a memory issue with the default Cloud9 servers. Meteor and Mongo together take up quite a bit of memory.

I wrote up a post talking about my exact setup and showing step-by-step how I got it set up and running here: http://simpleprogrammer.com/2014/10/13/getting-started-meteor-tutorial-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem:

```
$ cd ~/.meteor/tools/latest/mongodb/bin/mongo
$ ./mongod -v
./mongod: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./mongod)
```

My temporary solution: replace Meteor's [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) binaries with the installed version.

Comment: Thx, maybe its working for someone. My solution was to change from c9.io to nitrous.io ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bundled Meteor MongoDB complains about needing a newer version of GCC.

It is fixed on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) x86_64 using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
sudo apt-get install g++-4.6
```

(Thanks to this Super User question *[How can I update gcc to the latest version in Ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/310809)*.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get Meteor running on Cloud9 using the fix that Cugar Wang suggested. I used Cloud9's branch (Meteor 0.6.3.1) instead of manually patching the latest version of Meteor, as chaosbohne did.

Once you're in your Cloud9 project:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/c9/meteor
~/meteor/meteor # Initialize
mv ~/meteor/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod ~/meteor/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod_old # JIK
ln -s `which mongod` ~/meteor/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod
cd [projectDirectory]
~/meteor/meteor
```

I think this should be all you need for the general case. I was trying to get the angular-meteor-example to work, so I ran these commands first:

```
npm install -g meteorite
mrt add angularjs
```

I don't think installing Meteorite is necessary, but I haven't tested it.

FWIW: If you try to automatically apply Cloud9's patch to the current version of Meteor, you get an error:

```
curl -O https://github.com/c9/meteor/commit/075b83051e308793c278f979456a6ef88bc55d39.patch
git apply 075b83051e308793c278f979456a6ef88bc55d39.patch
error: tools/meteor.js: patch does not apply
...
```